# Heroku: Must I add a root domain?

Tags: heroku, dns, subdomain

[Heroku Dev Center: Custom Domain Names for Apps: Add a custom root domain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain) says:

> Root domains must be added in addition to any subdomains.

However, I was able to add a custom subodmain (eg, `api.foo.com`) for my Heroku app without adding a root domain (eg, `bar.com`), and everything seems to be working fine.

Must I really also add a root domain? If so, why?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add a root domain. The docs are just saying that IF you want a root domain added, you have to add it explicitly. (Adding api.foo.com doesn't implicitly add foo.com.)